# Mounting finned flat-base heat-sink with no tabs or screw-holes

Tags: heatsink

The heat sink has a flat base with no tabs or holes.

[image: Heat sink top]

[image: Heat sink bottom]

How is it supposed to be mounted on a PCB?

Wire brackets soldered to the PCB come to mind but then how does one ensure there's enough pressure between the heat sink and the PCB for good heat conduction?

Comment: Drill and tap your own,

Comment: The wire brackets are spring loaded or have clips. Like your motherboard.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to cool.  What is the heat source?  Watts?  Area? How much area around the heat source (top and bottom of PCB) is available for thermal management?

Answer (score 4):

Thermally conductive adhesive is often used between small heatsinks like this and the chip they're cooling. There are various silver, aluminium or ceramic loaded epoxies commercially available for the purpose.

Clamping is an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

These types of heatsinks are quite common on computer motherboards. I assume by "mounting on a PCB" you mean mounting it to an IC soldered onto a pcb. They are glued directly to the IC using special thermal glue. Once glued on they cannot be removed without possibly damaging the chip underneath.

Here is the link for some thermal glue :
[https://www.amazon.com/Conductive-Silicone-Adhesive-Compound-Heatsink/dp/B019MSKTX8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019MSKTX8)

To use the glue simply trace the outline of the chip with the glue and add a small drop of thermal paste in the center(if you want) then push the heatsink on and hold it until the glue sets.

Comment: Can this be glued to the copper on the PCB? When there's a surface mount plastic part e.g. in a TO-263 case? With plastic being a poor heat conductor I suppose one should attach it to the PCB and not the plastic case.

Comment: You should be able to do that provided it is close to the SMD part. Altough you might want to get a smaller heatsink, a 3cm X 3cm heatsink will waste a lot of surface area which you could otherwise use for routing traces.   Edit: typo

Comment: Also if the component you are using has a pad on the bottom it will help with the heat transfer but in a lot of cases the pad is usually connected to one of the pins of the component (usually GND) so be sure to use a electrically insulating mica film between the PCB and the component. This answer has some good info about mica sheets :https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/what-material-should-i-use-to-insulate-my-mosfet-from-a-heatsink

Answer (score 2):

*[In addition to what others have suggested already.]*

> Wire brackets soldered to the PCB come to mind but then how does one ensure there's enough pressure between the heat sink and the PCB for good heat conduction?

Heatsinks like that are often pressed to the IC with a purpose-made spring clip.  The ends of the spring clip attach to anchors soldered to the PCB.  The middle of the spring clip presses the heatsink to the IC.

[image], more drawings [here](https://www.micforg.co.jp/en/c_zclipe.html)

[image]

I've seen an arrangement like that on some of the desktop motherboards.

**related reading:**
How to choose a heat sink attachment method to secure your heat sink and for optimal heat transfer.  [Part 1](https://www.qats.com/cms/2010/09/17/how-to-choose-a-heat-sink-attachment-method-to-secure-your-heat-sink-and-for-optimal-heat-transfer-part-1-of-2/).  [Part 2](https://www.qats.com/cms/2010/09/20/how-to-choose-a-heat-sink-attachment-method-to-secure-your-heat-sink-and-for-optimal-heat-transfer-part-2-of-2/).